# MRI images "slideshow"

Tags: view, load, slideshow, dicom

If I have a series of MRI images in dicom file format, how would I upload them all and view them as a slideshow?

I have a folder, which contains a .dat file and 94 .dcm slices. I've tried "load" and got the following message:

```
>> load('dcmsermap.dat')
Error using load
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file
C:\Users\michelle\Desktop\COLAO\dcmsermap.dat
must be the same as previous lines.
```

"imread" and gotten the following:

```
>> imread('dcmsermap.dat')
Error using imread (line 382)
Unable to determine the file format.
```

I did textscan too and got similar error messages.

Answer (score 0):

A good option could be to create a DICOMDIR structure. Matlab seems to have functions to [read](http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7926-dicomdir-reader) dicomdir.

You can create easily the dicomdir structure using command line tools either from the [dcmtk](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmgpdir.html) toolkit or from the [dcm4che2](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/d2/dcmdir) one.

Comment: I tried this: 
    >> dcmSeries=loaddcmdir('COLAO');
    Undefined function 'loaddcmdir' for
    input arguments of type 'char'.
But I have only gotten the error message above. Do I need to load something before I can use dcmdir?

Comment: These type of errors are in some cases related to incorrect path names, or non ascii characters or spaces in these path names.